# Text not appening at the head of the file

Tags: python

I have the below code doing everything except what I want :-). The goal is simple, I am trying to add the text to appendtext variable at the top of each file present in the directory (and subdirectories), the script runs fine but the text is not getting appended. Where am I going wrong?

```py
import os
import sys
import fnmatch
temp_fname = "temp_file"

appendtext="""Test string
"""
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit('Usage: test.py <build directory>')

for path,dirs,files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for fname in files:
        for pat in ['*.*']:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname,pat):
                fullname = os.path.join(path,fname)
                with open(fullname, "r") as in_file:
                    with open(temp_fname, "w") as out_file:
                        out_file.write(appendtext)
                        for line in in_file:
                            out_file.write(line)
                os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)
```

Comment: "Append" means "add to end." What you want is to "prepend."

Comment: @FrancisAvila - problem is its not even appending the text at the end..if it works I can try to chagne to prepend

Comment: Does `print fnmatch.filter(files, pat)` produces anything?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I updated the code that works now..but wondering there is a better way other than creatng a temp_fname

Comment: The pattern `*.*` means "any filename that has at least one period in it".  If you just want "any filename" to match, use the pattern `*`, as I did in my answer.  I will now edit my answer to explain why you need to create a temp file.

Comment: you could use `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False)` instead of `open(temp_fname,'w')` and `shutil.copyfileobj()` instead of `for line ...` If you want to use binary file mode then make sure `appendtext` ends with `os.linesep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text at the top of the file, you should do something like this:

```
temp_fname = "temp_file"
# the next line doesn't work in Python 2.5, 2.6, or 3.0
with open(fullname, "r") as in_file, open(temp_fname, "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(appendtext)
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write(line)
os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)
```

Here is the above rewritten for Python 2.6:

```
temp_fname = "temp_file"
with open(temp_fname, "w") as out_file:
    with open(fullname, "r") as in_file:
        out_file.write(appendtext)
        for line in in_file:
            out_file.write(line)
os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)
```

We can do a little better than this. This always uses the same temporary filename (`"temp_file"`) and that file will always be created in a single directory (the default directory when you run this).  What we really want is a temporary file, with a unique name, created in exactly the same directory as the file we will be editing.  Python provides us with a handy module called `tempfile` which creates temporary files.

By default, you just get an open file handle and you don't know the filename.  But we need to know the filename, so that after the temp copy is fully done, we can rename it to the original file name.  `tempfile` provides `NamedTemporaryFile` for cases like this.

Here is a complete program:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
import tempfile

headertext = "# header text\n\n"

def want_this_file(fname):
    for pat in ['*']:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname, pat):
            return True
    return False

def prepend_file(fullname, path):
    # with statement means temp file is written and closed at end of with
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=path, delete=False) as out_file:
        with open(fullname, "r") as in_file:
                out_file.write(headertext)
                for line in in_file:
                    out_file.write(line)
        # before temp file is closed, get its name
        temp_fname = out_file.name
    # rename temp file to fullname, clobbering original
    os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)


start_directory = sys.argv[1]

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_directory):
    for fname in filenames:
        if want_this_file(fname):
            fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
            prepend_file(fullname, dirpath)
```

This answer uses the pattern "write a temp file, then rename the temp file to the original name".  This is the way you should do it.  It lets the code write the new version, and only when the new version is fully and successfully written, *then* does a single action to rename the new file to the old filename.  Thus, if anything goes wrong while trying to write the new version, the original file is left untouched.  This is a safe way to solve the problem.

We want to create the temp file in the same directory as the original file, so that the `os.rename()` operation will be trivially cheap.  On a Linux system, your system temp directory (`/tmp`) might be on its own partition, and if you just let `tempfile` create its temporary file there, then the rename operation might involve copying the data again!  If the temp file is in the same directory, the rename operation is always very fast and safe.

EDIT: Here is an improved version of the code.  This catches errors, and cleans up the temp file before re-raising the exception signalling the error.  Also, as J.F. Sebastian pointed out, the files should be opened in binary mode; this does that.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile

file_patterns_to_match = ['*']

headertext = "# header text\n\n"
# make any newlines in headertext match the system line ending
headertext = headertext.replace('\n', os.linesep)

def want_this_file(fname):
    for pat in file_patterns_to_match:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(fname, pat):
            return True
    return False

def prepend_file(fullname, path):
    # with statement means temp file is written and closed at end of with
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=path, delete=False) as out_file:
        # get the name immediately
        temp_fname = out_file.name

        try:
            # use binary mode to avoid newline translations
            with open(fullname, "rb") as in_file:
                out_file.write(headertext)
                shutil.copyfileobj(in_file, out_file)
        except Exception:
            # on any error, clean up temp file and re-raise exception
            try:
                os.remove(temp_fname)
            except Exception:
                print("unable to clean up temp file: " + temp_fname)
                pass
            raise
    # rename temp file to fullname, clobbering original
    os.rename(temp_fname, fullname)


start_directory = sys.argv[1]

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_directory):
    for fname in filenames:
        if want_this_file(fname):
            fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
            prepend_file(fullname, dirpath)
```

Comment: steveha - am using pythong 2.6.5,its giving compilation error at with open(fullname, "r") as in_file, open(temp_fname, "w") as out_file:
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax, is there a way we can do this without creating a temp file in python 2.6.5

Comment: You can do this without a temp file by reading the entire file into memory and then overwriting the file. *However*, a temp file is much safer and uses less memory. It is *impossible* to prepend to a file without writing out the whole file again.

Comment: I have updated this to show how to nest the `with` statements in Python 2.6.  The version that uses `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` already uses nested `with` statements and should work for you.

Comment: you should use either text or binary mode (use os.linesep for headertext in this case) for files everywhere otherwise newlines might be corrupted. shutil.copyfileobj and fnmatch.filter might simplify the code.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, those are excellent points.  I was already editing to make a new version that cleans up the temp file if any error occurs; I'll look at your suggestions now.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, `fnmatch.filter` doesn't seem like a good fit here, since the original code suggests a list of possible extensions to match.  `shutil.copyfileobj` replaces a simple two-line loop with one line, not a huge win, but might speed the code since it pushes the copying down into Python itself.  The temp file is opened in binary mode by default, and now I modified the code to open the input file in binary mode.  See updated code at end of answer.

Comment: for a list of patterns I'd use a combined regex instead. copyfileobj handles arbitrary large lines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22425/discussion-between-steveha-and-j-f-sebastian)

Comment: @steveha - Lets say I want to add one more feature to this like ..if the file has  a multiline comment where one-line matches the string "Test 2012, Test foundation. All tests",I want to delete the whole comment,not jsut the line...how difficult it is do  it?

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is about your python script. But you can achieve this in a one liner in bash using perl.

```
sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ cat file_0*
Hi - 1 
Hi - 2 
Hi - 3 
Hi - 4 
Hi - 5 

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ find . -type f
./file_01.txt
./file_02.txt
./file_03.txt
./file_04.txt
./file_05.txt

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ find . -type f -exec  perl -pi -e 'print "Please donot add any comments \nThis is a header file.\nJust a test.\n" if $. == 1' {} \;

sgeorge-mn:stack sgeorge$ cat file_0*
Please donot add any comments 
This is a header file.
Just a test.
Hi - 1 
Please donot add any comments 
This is a header file.
Just a test.
Hi - 2 
Please donot add any comments 
This is a header file.
Just a test.
Hi - 3 
Please donot add any comments 
This is a header file.
Just a test.
Hi - 4 
Please donot add any comments 
This is a header file.
Just a test.
Hi - 5
```

Comment: `find /start/dir -type f -exec sed -i '1i line to prepend' {} +`